# Lerp in Coroutine not running

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the coroutine below to try to scale a transform from Vector3.zero to Vector3.one over one second (scalingTime).  I've determined that the coroutine is definitely being run, but the object is not scaling.  Am I using the "yield return null" in the while loop correctly?

```
IEnumerator ScaleLaser()
{
    float elapsedTime = 0;
    float scalingTime = 1;
    Vector3 currentScale = laser.localScale;

    while (elapsedTime < scalingTime)
    {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(currentScale, Vector3.one, elapsedTime / scalingTime);
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are editing "transform.localScale". You should set laser.transform.localScale

Comment: @Cenkisabi Ahh thank you. Mistakes made after a long day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
IEnumerator ScaleLaser()
{
    float scalingTime = 1;
    float time = 0;

    while (time < 1)
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime / scalingTime;
        laser.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(laser.localScale, Vector3.one, time);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```